# Has there been any proposals to onboard new users in creating EOS accounts without the need to pay for it?

Tags: accounts, account-creation

The EOS account name system is great for newcomers to crypto. But the fact that you have to "pay" to create an account kind of kills the onboarding of new users to the EOS ecosystem. Are there any proposals or solutions to solve this UX issue of getting more EOS users to come on?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There's also [Scatter Bridge](https://get-scatter.com/bridge) coming soon.

Answer (score 0):

No official solutions by anyone as this is not a centrally controlled project.
Some participants offer from time to time free account creation with their own terms and limitations. Here are a few recent offers based on a google search for "eos free account creation":

- [Meet.one](https://medium.com/@MEET.ONE/1000-free-eos-accounts-from-meet-one-a03083509507)
- [Infinito Wallet](https://www.infinitowallet.io/register-your-eos-account-name-for-free-now-just-three-easy-steps-with-infinito-wallet/)
- [EOS Asia](https://medium.com/@eosasia/eos-asia-gives-out-free-eos-accounts-a51354d7d8d)

Every one of those is an attempt to get new users to know the EOS blockchain and be new users of those services on top of the EOS blockchain.

The problem with funding free accounts for users is the possibility for abuse where someone creates multiple accounts for themselves.

Block.one, which is the largest stakeholder in the EOS blockchain is rumored to be developing a social network and Daniel Larimer claimed he found a solution to proving uniqueness of users to prevent the multiple accounts for one user. Block.one will probably have free account creation for new users of their social network.

Once a user has an account he can use all the dApps on the blockchain with that account, so the cost will be free for any dApp if they let their users know they need to register first with a free account creation service and then use their dApp.